# Interfaces design best practices (separate interfaces vs inheritance)

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, interface

I have an element with complex id (consists from 2 Guids) and I need to represent an element with two interfaces (interface of the element id and interface of the element itself, with it's properties), so, I have two options for it:

Option #1:

```
interface IElementId {
    Guid Id1;
    Guid Id2;
}

interface IElement : IElementId {
    string Name;
    string Type;
    ...etc
}
```

The key point here - both ids (Guids) are part of the element itself, so IElement "includes" IElementId in itself by inheritance.

Option #2:

```
interface IElementId {
    Guid Id1;
    Guid Id2;
}

interface IElement {
    IElementId Id;
    string Name;
    string Type;
    ...etc
}
```

The point here - Id is a separate property represented by the separate interface and is included in the element as property of the IElementId interface type.

It is not easy to find best desing practices and advices for this case, so, please, feel free and be welcome to share your opinion about option #1 vs option #2.

Comment: What about Option 3? Keep both interfaces completely separate. So, if you have a class just implement both interfaces. Or, make a third interface that includes both interfaces if you really want to have both together.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear as to what you are after.
Designing systems around the implementation of interfaces is to be lauded as by use of the factory pattern it allows for substitution at runtime, and unit testing but also is a good indicator of whether a short cut is being taken that may be difficult to support in future.

Let's look at what you have:

**Option #1**

This option is my preferred as you can use the double `Guid` property type in multiple class types as concrete implementations of `IElement` and they can also be used in code that relates only to `IElementId`.

Thus, if you had classes implementing:

```
interface IElementTwo : IElementId
{
    string SomthingDifferent {get;set;}
}
```

Then you could sort a list of concrete classes implementing `IElement` and `IElementTwo`. So, class `Element` implements `IElement` and a class `ElementTwo` implements `IElementTwo`:

```
var list = new List<IElementId>();
list.Add(new Element() { Id1 = Guid.NewGuid(), Id2 = Guid.NewGuid(), Name="One" });
list.Add(new Element() { Id1 = Guid.NewGuid(), Id2 = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Two" });
list.Add(new Element() { Id1 = Guid.NewGuid(), Id2 = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Three" });
list.Add(new ElementTwo(){Id1 = Guid.NewGuid(), Id2 = Guid.NewGuid(), Something ="This"});
list.Add(new ElementTwo(){Id1 = Guid.NewGuid(), Id2 = Guid.NewGuid(), Something = "That"});
var result = list.OrderBy(x=>x.Id1).ThenBy(x=>x.Id2).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Option #2**

This isn't quite as flexible as the previous option. In this case the double `Guid` identifiers are really only relevant to those classes that implement `IElement`, but that may be what you are after in your code design, but once this choice is taken it would be more difficult to add the double Guid identifier to another class and use it in the same code as `Element`.

Note that the thing about interfaces is that they are not restricted in the way that concrete class inheritance is thus you can have:

```
internal interface IElementIdOne
{
    Guid Id1 { get; set; }
}
internal interface IElementIdTwo
{
    Guid Id2 { get; set; }
}
internal interface IElementId : IElementIdOne, IElementIdTwo
{
    Guid Id1 { get; set; }
    Guid Id2 { get; set; }
}
```

It's not uncommon to come across composite merged classes, particularly if data has been retrieved from a data table with a relationship:

```
internal interface IElementIdOne
{
    Guid Id1 { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
internal interface IElementIdTwo
{
    Guid Id2 { get; set; }
    string SomethingElse { get; set; }
}

class CompositeElement : IElementIdOne, IElementIdTwo
{
    public Guid Id1 { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Id2 { get; set; }
    public string SomethingElse { get; set; }
}
```